# Is in PHP a function which can check if string is a extension?

Tags: php

Is In PHP a function which can check if string is a extension of a file? For example:

```
$q = 'txt';

if ( is_extension($q) )
{
    echo "yee, this is a extension";
}
else
{
    echo "no, this isn't any extension";
}
```

I have a URL, for example: http://example.com/user-name/user-dir/any-file-to-download.txt(text). I would like to check if this URL contain any extension and check if this extension is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to assert that it conforms to the MIME identifier syntax? Including attributes? Or that it's a known MIME type? (Btw. `txt` isn't one. That would be `text/plain`)

Comment: I have a URL, for example: http://example.com/user-name/user-dir/any-file-to-download.txt(text). I would like to check if this URL contain any extension and check if this extension is correct.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. But anyway, you always could call [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: What do you mean by *extension is correct*?

Answer (score 1):

[`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) comes to the rescue:

```
echo pathinfo('http://example.com/a.txt', PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//⇒ txt
```

To check against permitted exts:

```
echo in_array(
  pathinfo('http://example.com/a.txt', PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
  array('txt','html')
);
//⇒ 1
```

Though above is doing it’s job, checking `MIME`-type is way more error-prone and handy.

Comment: OK, but what if we have a link like this: http://example.com/user-name/user-dir/any-file-to-download.txxxt(text)? pathinfo return "txxxt(text)". We know - this extension isn't correct. How I can check if extension is correct?

Comment: txt = correct extension because MIME TYPE of this extension is: text/plain.
 txxxt = this isn't correct extension because MIME TYPE of this extension doesn't exist.

Comment: WUT? Though there are some lists of known MIME-types [maintained](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-file-extension.htm), there is no such a thing like ”correct extension” and/or “MIME-type exists.” Everybody might introduce her own MIME-type. It’s perfectly permitted to set a MIME-type of something to `application/x-whatever`. This MIME-type is perfectly correct, though in your terms it’s inexisting.

Comment: @mudasobwa If you want the correct extension in your view than you have only option and that is to create an array. Anybody can make his/her new extension

Comment: @Hudixt I know, as you might see from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pathinfo()` function in php to get the extension. TO check if the extension is correct or not you will have to make a array of extensions. Use the code below

```
<?php

      $url = ' http://example.com/user-name/user-dir/any-file-to-download.txt(text)';
        $array = array("txt","doc");


        $extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($extension !=="" && in_array($extension, $array)){
        echo "It has extension and that is ".$extension ;
        }
        else{
        echo "It doesn't have extension";
        }
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: OK but when I can find all types of extensions? If I have to create an array with extensions, I need list of all extensions.

Comment: `parse_url` makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: Just added in case if the OP wants something more like getting the name of the domain or something else, updated my answer.